# Hide first post from specific category in loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, hide

I'm having a normal wordpress loop, but I want to always hide the most recent post from a specific category from this loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean variable to check whether you've already skipped one post in that category, like this:

```
<?php 
$post_has_been_skipped = FALSE;
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        if (!$post_has_been_skipped AND in_category("your-category-slug")) {
            $post_has_been_skipped = TRUE;
            continue;
        }
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$categories = array();
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
                    $category = the_category();
                    if (in_array($category)) {
                            the_post(); // code after the 1st one is skipped.
                    } else {
                            $categories[] = $category; // when it's the first post, add the category so the next posts will display.
                    }
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

This should be the basic structure of your loop.

Logic: If the category is the first, it doesn't exist in $categories, so it adds it and moved on the the next post, if that category is already in the array it displays the code.